# Sitecore 7 ContentSearch crawling failure: "Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed"

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

When we try to rebuild our Lucene (ContentSearch) indexes, our CrawlingLog is filled up with these exceptions:

```
7052 15:08:21 WARN  Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed - {5A1E50E4-46B9-42D5-B743-1ED10D15D47E}
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.PartitionerForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](Partitioner`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 simpleBody, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractDocumentBuilder`1.AddItemFields()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.CrawlerLuceneIndexOperations.GetIndexData(IIndexable indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.CrawlerLuceneIndexOperations.BuildDataToIndex(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexable version)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.CrawlerLuceneIndexOperations.Add(IIndexable indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, ProviderIndexConfiguration indexConfiguration)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoAdd(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.HierarchicalDataCrawler`1.CrawlItem(Tuple`3 tuple)
Nested Exception
Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
Source: mscorlib
   at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
   at Sitecore.Data.ShortID.Encode(String guid)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.MultiListFieldReader.GetFieldValue(IIndexableDataField indexableField)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap.GetFieldValue(IIndexableDataField field)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddField(IIndexableDataField field)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass32`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__30()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__10(Object param0)
```

This appears to be caused by the `ShortID.Encode(string)` method expecting the GUID in the string parameter to have brackets (" { " and " } ") around it. Some of our multilist field relationships were associated programmatically using `Guid.ToString()`, which does not include the brackets. Unfortunately, these values cause the `ShortID.Encode()` method to choke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First things first: find all the places you call `MultiListField.Add(string)` and change `Guid.ToString()` to `Guid.ToString("B")`. This will resolve the issue for all new relationships.
2. Create a custom `FieldReader` class to replace the standard `MultiListFieldReader` (we called ours `CustomMultiListFieldReader`).
3. Set your custom class to inherit from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReader`.
4. Decompile the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.MultiListFieldReader.GetFieldValue(IIndexableDataField)` method into your custom class.
5. Before the `if (ID.IsID(id))` line, add the following code:

   ```
   if (!str.StartsWith("{") && !str.EndsWith("}"))
       id = String.Format("{{{0}}}", str);
   ```
6. In your index configuration (we added ours to the default, `Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`) change the fieldReaderType for the MultiList fields to your custom type. (This can be found in your config at sitecore/contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/fieldReaders/mapFieldByTypeName/fieldReader.)

Full disclosure: I don't love this approach because if the default implementation of the `MultiListFieldReader` ever changed, we'd be without those changes. But this allows the items to be included in the index without reformatting all of the GUIDs in every multilist field.